# Can Intel Xeon Phi get data direct from another PCI device?

Tags: intel, xeon-phi

Can Intel Xeon Phi be configured to receive data direct from FPGA board, process them and send result to host memory?

I have large flow of input data and don't want to have redundant transfers (FPGA board ->Host Memory->MIC->Host Memory) over PCI. I want more elegant scheme (FPGA board-> MIC->Host Memory) Is it possible?

Comment: I believe the answer is yes, but need to check on the details. I recall a discussion on directly accessing an ssd from the coprocessor over the PCIe bus. I'll dig it out.

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't know, this question was posted and it receives some comments at Intel Many Integrated Core Architecture Forum https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/540368